# Minimal Bash-like line editing is supporting. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, kubuntu

Firstly, I'm new to Linux. I bought a laptop from a seller who claimed it has Ubuntu installed. When I first turned on the computer, I see the following screen:

"Minimal Bash-like line editing is supporting. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions."

How can I fix this? Thank you.

[Boot Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBggF.jpg)

[Main Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY25l.jpg)

Comment: Does it say grub? So it does not boot. Try to change the booted partition used by BIOS (mostly F12 or F11 or F10 is needed to be pressed during boot process). If it does not help, forget the crap and install Ubuntu as a fresh install! Why not do it new? That will work quite sure.